# Does canActivate works for ionic2 page navigation

Tags: angular, ionic2

I tried to use canActivate on ionic2, but it seems to have no effect. 
I am trying to create an authentication mechanism. 
The method called on the canActivate is

```
static requireAuth(): boolean {
    const { auth, router } = AuthRouteHelper;
    console.log('requiring auth');
    if (!auth.authenticated) router.navigate(['/Login']);
    return auth.authenticated;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Note for whomever wondering, this feature is not working in ionic2 at this time. You need to find a workaround for this. In my case I check for the login, and redirect based on that.

Comment: hey did you had a look on "onPage*" states of an Ionic Page? Nevertheless do you know how to "resolve" data before rendering of a page occurs?

Comment: Not sure if I understand you, but I use observable/emitters to update the properties of the page after render, which triggers another render, but it is fine.

Comment: Probably i wasn't clear enough, sorry. I did a writeup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36569179/ionic2-equivalent-resolve-canactivate maybe you can have a look and share your thoughts

Answer (score -1):

canActivate is not working because ionic used NavController