# Get data async before a `Page` gets rendered

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

What is the correct way to get data async before a `Page` gets rendered?

`Angular2` suggests the `@CanActivate` decorator as far as I understand it. Sadly this is not working with Ionic2, at least not for me and for [others](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/what-is-the-equivalent-of-resolve-in-ionic-2/37679/15)

Apparently `Ionic2` does something with the `@CanActivate` decorator, [see](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-code/blob/c546dcf7dcbf334df349b45db81fbec9718d9fea/2.0.0/js/router.dev.js) 
But its not documented and i can't figure out what it does exactly.

Nevertheless [this guy](https://webcake.co/page-lifecycle-hooks-in-ionic-2/) points out one should use `Ionics View States` instead anyways, due to ionics caching. His example looks like this:

```
  onPageWillEnter() { 
      return this._service.getComments().then(data => this.comments = data);
  }
```

Which looks like he is expecting Ionic to consider the returned promise, but a [quick glance](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-code/blob/c546dcf7dcbf334df349b45db81fbec9718d9fea/2.0.0/components/nav/view-controller.js) a Ionics sources reveals (at least I think so) that the returned value is ignored. Hence there is no guarantee that the promise gets resolved *before* the page gets rendered. Here is an [example](https://plnkr.co/edit/jF9QAcPwGY97cW9dQ7x0) with onPage* and how it does not perform as needed/expected.

So I'm lost, how does one achieve this simple task?

In the first link, it was suggested to resolve the data before navigating to the page, which burdens the knowledge which data is needed for the page on the callee. This is not an option in my opinion.

*edit: added negative example

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For anyone crawling Stackoverflow about *restricting* page access when using Ionic 2, it looks like Ionic's recommended lifecycle event to tap into is `ionViewCanEnter`.

**From the docs:**

> **ionViewCanEnter** Runs before the view can enter. This can be used as a sort of "guard" in authenticated views where you need to check permissions before the view can enter.

http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/NavController/

Comment: Very good, I was 'crawling Stackoverflow about restricting page access when using Ionic 2' :)

Comment: This is the correct answer and should be ranked higher... i finally made sense of it and here is a plunker I got working - http://embed.plnkr.co/B8XPvV/

Comment: Angular had a way to apply the `canActivate` to entire routes and related children. If there was a way to apply this guard to all pages within a module, it would save a lot of `ionViewCanEnter` code scattered around.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure if this is the *official way* to do it, but I use the `Loading` component for situations like this one. You can find more information in [Ionic API Docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/loading/Loading/).

The page `.ts` file would look like this:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Loading, NavController} from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  templateUrl:"page1.html"
})
export class Page1 {
  // Loading component
  loading : any;
  // Information to obtain from server
  comments: string = '';

  constructor(nav: NavController) {
    this.nav = nav;
  }

  onPageWillEnter() {
    // Starts the process 
    this.showLoading();
  }

  private showLoading() {
    this.loading = Loading.create({
      content: "Please wait..."
    });
    // Show the loading page
    this.nav.present(this.loading);
    // Get the Async information 
    this.getAsyncData();
  }

  private getAsyncData() {

    // this simulates an async method like
    // this._service.getComments().then((data) => { 
    //     this.comments = data);
    //     this.hideLoading();
    // });

    setTimeout(() => {
      // This would be the part of the code inside the => {...}
      this.comments = "Data retrieved from server";
      // Hide the loading page
      this.hideLoading();
    }, 5000);
  }

  private hideLoading(){
    // Hide the loading component
    this.loading.dismiss();
  }
}
```

The code is very simple so it doesn't need further details, the idea is to define a `loading` so we can show it, then try to obtain the information, and as soon as we get that data, we can hide it calling the `this.loading.dismiss()` method.

You can find a [working plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/R6UQvxyPghOlLK3rKRWb?p=preview) (using beta.9)

Comment: This is by far the best "workaround" I've seen so far. Thank you very much

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: I do not know why, but the view will load before the async bits no matter what solution I use ..

Answer (score 1):

If you only navigate to that page from one location, couldn't you simply load the data before navigating and using the `NavParams` to pass the data?

I am using this structure for a Profile page, from a certain index page I click on a user, and then retrieve his profile before visiting his profile. You can show a nice `Loading` while this is happening.

```
let self=this;
this.profileSvc.getProfile(id)
.then(profile => {
    self.nav.push(Profile, {profile:profile});
});
```

Now in the Profile page you can use the `NavParams` to initialize your page.

```
export class Profile {
    profile:any;
    constructor(private params:NavParams) {
        if(params.get('profile')) {
            this.profile = params.get('profile');
        } else {
            this.profile = this.me;
        }
    }
```