# How to retrieve information of a loan (loan document fields) and the items within the specific loan (items collection of loan document) from firebase?

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get the information of a specific loan by it's ID and the details of items in that loan to display it in the detail page. However, I am unable to and I do not know how to retrieve the loan and loan items using the loan service's getLoanById method given to me.

***detail.page.ts***

```
export class DetailPage {
  loan: Loan;
  loanId: string;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private loanService: LoanService) {
    this.loanId = this.route.snapshot.params.id;
    this.loan = this.loanService.getLoanById(this.loanId);
  }
}
```

***loan.service.ts***

```
  getLoanById(id: string) {
    return firebase.firestore().collection('loans').doc(id).get().then(doc => {
      let loan = new Loan(doc.data().username, doc.data().status, doc.data().duedate.toDate(), doc.id);

      return firebase.firestore().collection('loans/' + id + '/items').get().then(collection => {
        loan.items = []; // Empty array
        collection.forEach(doc => {
          let item = new Item(doc.id, doc.data().quantity);
          loan.items.push(item);
        })
        return loan;
      });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `getLoanById()` to the following method:

```
 async getLoanById(id: string) : Promise<any> {
    const doc = await firebase.firestore().collection('loans').doc(id).get();
    let loan = new Loan(doc.data().username, doc.data().status, doc.data().duedate.toDate(), doc.id);
    const collection = await firebase.firestore().collection('loans/' + id + '/items').get();
    loan.items = []; // Empty array
    collection.forEach(doc_1 => {
      let item = new Item(doc_1.id, doc_1.data().quantity);
      loan.items.push(item);
    });
    return loan;
  }
```

Since the `get()` method is asynchronous, therefore use `async/await` to wait until the data is retrieved to then add it to the list. Then inside the `DetailPage` you can do the following:

```
   constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private loanService: LoanService) {
    this.loanId = this.route.snapshot.params.id;
    this.loanService.getLoanById(this.loanId).then((result){
      console.log(result);
     });
  }
```

The then() method returns a `Promise`. It takes up to two arguments: callback functions for the success and failure cases of the `Promise`. Once a Promise is fulfilled or rejected, the respective handler function (onFulfilled or onRejected) will be called asynchronously.

Check:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: The detail.page.html now loads faster than the data being retrieved from firebase causing the page to only load partially. Is there a way to fully retrieve the firebase data before loading the page?

Comment: Yes the html will load before because this call is asynchronous , usually since you are using angular and ionic then just implement `OnInit` class and override the method `ngOnInit()`  call `getLoanById()`. Also use the component https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/loading to show a small spinner before loading the data and dismiss it after data is loaded

Comment: I've impmeneted the OnInit class but I am unable to figure out how to override the method ngOnInit() to call getLoanById().

Comment: after implementing it, isnt it giving you an error? Just write `ngOnInit() {}`

Comment: I did write ngOnInit(){} but am I supposed to write anything in the ngOnInit method as the html is still loading first.

Comment: html will also load first... but with `ngOnInit` the asychronous call will get called only once.. and when you use the loadingcontroller you can then handle what to show in the html until data is retrieved. Check this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38014256/7015400

Comment: I've found that you can prevent the html components that require the firestore data from loading until you have fully retrieved the data by adding an "*ngIf=loan" to it. This checks if the loan is retrieved yet before attempting to display it in html.